# How to convert Unix timestamp into Swift NSDate object?

Tags: swift, nsdate, unix-timestamp

I'm getting dates as [Unix timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) through my API and I want to convert them into NSDate objects in Swift.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why down vote and close this question ?? It is very legitimate for a new iOS programmer. I actually found this question because I was asking myself the same thing.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try this:

```
var date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInterval)
```

Comment: Was that timeInterval is Double type?

Comment: It's a `NSTimeInterval`, which as of Swift 2.2 is defined as `public typealias NSTimeInterval = Double`