# Parsing JSON (date) to Swift

Tags: ios, json, parsing, swift

I have a return JSON in my application in Swift, and have a field that returns me a date. When I refer to this data, the code gives me something like "/ Date (1420420409680) /". How do I convert this into NSDate? In Swift, please, I´ve tested examples with Objective-C, without success.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26844132/how-to-convert-unix-timestamp-into-swift-nsdate-object

Comment: It's a plain old UNIX timestamp.

Comment: @HotLicks: ... only in milliseconds (or it would be in the year 46981 :)

Comment: @MartinR - Yeah, you recognize it by the leading "14", and then you have to figure out whether it's seconds, milliseconds, or microseconds by counting the digits.  (And in one case I ran into it was even 10s of nanoseconds.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That looks very similar to the  JSON encoding for a date as used by Microsoft's ASP.NET AJAX, which
is described in [An Introduction to JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) in JavaScript and .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx#intro_to_json_topic2):

> For example, Microsoft's ASP.NET AJAX uses neither of the described
>   conventions. Rather, it encodes .NET DateTime values as a JSON string,
>   where the content of the string is /Date(ticks)/ and where ticks
>   represents milliseconds since epoch (UTC). So November 29, 1989,
>   4:55:30 AM, in UTC is encoded as "\/Date(628318530718)\/".

The only difference is that you have the format `/Date(ticks)/`
and not `\/Date(ticks)\/`.

You have to extract the number between the parentheses. Dividing that by 1000
gives the number in seconds since 1 January 1970.

The following code shows how that could be done. It is implemented as
a "failable convenience initializer" for `NSDate`:

```
extension NSDate {
    convenience init?(jsonDate: String) {

        let prefix = "/Date("
        let suffix = ")/"
        // Check for correct format:
        if jsonDate.hasPrefix(prefix) && jsonDate.hasSuffix(suffix) {
            // Extract the number as a string:
            let from = jsonDate.startIndex.advancedBy(prefix.characters.count)
            let to = jsonDate.endIndex.advancedBy(-suffix.characters.count)
            // Convert milliseconds to double
            guard let milliSeconds = Double(jsonDate[from ..< to]) else {
                return nil
            }
            // Create NSDate with this UNIX timestamp
            self.init(timeIntervalSince1970: milliSeconds/1000.0)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage (with your date string):

```
if let theDate = NSDate(jsonDate: "/Date(1420420409680)/") {
    print(theDate)
} else {
    print("wrong format")
}
```

This gives the output

```
2015-01-05 01:13:29 +0000
```

---

**Update for Swift 3 (Xcode 8):**

```
extension Date {
    init?(jsonDate: String) {

        let prefix = "/Date("
        let suffix = ")/"

        // Check for correct format:
        guard jsonDate.hasPrefix(prefix) && jsonDate.hasSuffix(suffix) else { return nil }

        // Extract the number as a string:
        let from = jsonDate.index(jsonDate.startIndex, offsetBy: prefix.characters.count)
        let to = jsonDate.index(jsonDate.endIndex, offsetBy: -suffix.characters.count)

        // Convert milliseconds to double
        guard let milliSeconds = Double(jsonDate[from ..< to]) else { return nil }

        // Create NSDate with this UNIX timestamp
        self.init(timeIntervalSince1970: milliSeconds/1000.0)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
if let theDate = Date(jsonDate: "/Date(1420420409680)/") {
    print(theDate)
} else {
    print("wrong format")
}
```

Comment: @Martin this extension fails for a value like: "/Date(1479119050805+0300)/" because the Double init method of milliseconds cannot return a double for the value of 1479119050805+0300 due to the plus sign, if you manage to handle this case please share your code here

Comment: @JAHelia: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/33166980/1187415 for a newer version which reads JSON dates with or without timezone offset.

Answer (score 2):

Adding onto what the others have provided, simply create utility method in your class below:

```
  func dateFromStringConverter(date: String)-> NSDate? {
    //Create Date Formatter
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    //Specify Format of String to Parse
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" //or you can use "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"
    //Parse into NSDate
    let dateFromString : NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date)!

    return dateFromString
}
```

Then you can call this method in your successfully returned, parsed JSON object, like below:

```
//Parse the date
 guard let datePhotoWasTaken = itemDictionary["date_taken"] as? String else {return}
     YourClassModel.dateTakenProperty = self.dateFromStringConverter(datePhotoWasTaken)
```

Or you can ignore the utility method and the caller code above entirely and simply do this:

```
//Parse the date
 guard let datePhotoWasTaken = itemDictionary["date_taken"] as? NSString else {return}
     YourClassModel.dateTakenProperty = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: datePhotoWasTaken.doubleValue)
```

And that should work!

Comment: The question is about parsing a string like `"/Date(1420420409680)/"`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an UNIX Timestamp: 01/12/2015 @ 6:14pm (UTC) [According to http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php ]

You can convert it to an NSDate object using the constructor NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: unixTimestamp)

Comment: And how I get timespan of this variable?