# How to convert firebase timestamp into date in iOS objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

I've kept my data in firebase with TIMESTAMP generated by firebase. I need to convert them in my iOS app. I tried to do it in following manner but returns complicated result.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1493292606524];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", date);
```

It returns `Date: 49290-07-23 05:48:44 +0000`

What is the issue of above? Result should be today date.  (2017-04-27)

Comment: But 49290-07-23 05:48:44 +0000 is correct :) You can check it here for example http://www.unixtimestamp.com

Comment: please refer this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854066/convert-timestamp-into-nsdate-swift

Comment: what date formate did you want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> try this need to convert this stamp into seconds

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(1493292606524/1000)];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", date);
```

Comment: Date: 2017-04-27 11:30:06 +0000
giving me this result change this data into required format