# How to convert date like \/Date(1440156888750-0700)\/ to something that Swift can handle?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, date

so in my app, I need to deal with date like `\/Date(1440156888750-0700)\/`, i think the first part stands for the seconds from Jan 1st, 1970 and the second part is the timezone.
I don't know how to handle data like this and display it the way we all understand in Xcode 7 using Swift 2?

Comment: From where do you get this date/string? Also, reading the [NSDate class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/index.html) might be able to help you.

Comment: minor correction, the first part are the *milli*seconds from 1970.

Answer (score 8):

*(The previous version of this answer was actually wrong, it did not handle the time zone correctly.)*

According to [Stand-Alone JSON Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx):

> DateTime values appear as JSON strings in the form of "/Date(700000+0500)/", where the first number (700000 in the example provided) is the number of milliseconds in the GMT time zone, regular (non-daylight savings) time since midnight, January 1, 1970. The number may be negative to represent earlier times. The part that consists of "+0500" in the example is optional and indicates that the time is of the Local kind - that is, should be converted to the local time zone on deserialization. If it is absent, the time is deserialized as Utc. The actual number ("0500" in this example) and its sign (+ or -) are ignored.

and [Use JSON.NET to parse json date of format Date(epochTime-offset)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33224540/use-json-net-to-parse-json-date-of-format-dateepochtime-offset/33228106#33228106)

> ... In this [screwy format][1], the timestamp portion is still based solely on UTC.  The offset is *extra* information. It doesn't change the timestamp.  You can give a different offset, or omit it entirely and it's still the same moment in time.

the first number in `\/Date(1440156888750-0700)\/` is the number of
milliseconds since the "epoch" January 1, 1970 GMT, and the time
zone part `-0700` must simply be *ignored.*

Here is a **Swift 5** extension method for `Date` which checks 
the validity of the string with a regular expression 
(accepting both `\/Date(...)\/` and `/Date(...)/`, with or without
a time zone specification) and converts the given number of
milliseconds to a `Date`:

```
extension Date {
    init?(jsonDate: String) {

        let pattern = #"\\?/Date\((\d+)([+-]\d{4})?\)\\?/"#
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
        guard let match = regex.firstMatch(in: jsonDate, range: NSRange(jsonDate.startIndex..., in: jsonDate)) else {
            return nil
        }

        // Extract milliseconds:
        let dateString = jsonDate[Range(match.range(at: 1), in: jsonDate)!]
        // Convert to UNIX timestamp in seconds:
        let timeStamp = Double(dateString)! / 1000.0
        // Create Date from timestamp:
        self.init(timeIntervalSince1970: timeStamp)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let jsonDate = "\\/Date(1440156888750-0700)\\/"
print("JSON Date:", jsonDate)

if let theDate = Date(jsonDate: jsonDate) {
    print("Date:", theDate)
} else {
    print("wrong format")
}
```

Output:

```
JSON Date: \/Date(1440156888750-0700)\/
Date: 2015-08-21 11:34:48 +0000
```

(Versions for Swift 3 and Swift 4 can be found in the edit history.)

Comment: I thought about a solution like this as well - just adding or removing a TimeInterval from the timestamp date based on the timezone but I did not like the fact that you completely loose any timezone information present in the original string.

Comment: @luk2302: I do not understand what you mean. "+-HHMM" is converted to a timezone offset in seconds to adjust the time value. There is no information lost.

Comment: What I mean is that the correct date in GMT is returned - YES. But you loose the information that the original date was given in a different timezone. Which is indicated exactly by the +0000 in the final output - you loose the -0700 in timezone information.

Comment: @luk2302: What? The result is an NSDate, which is an absolute point in time and  has no timezone information. Its description always uses GMT. (Btw, the output is identical to that of your method.)

Comment: @luk2302: As I found out later, the time zone part "-0700" must be ignored for the conversion to a Date`.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of experimenting around I came up with the following solution:

```
let dx = "/Date(1440156888750-0700)/"
let timestamp = (dx as NSString).substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 6,length: 13))
let timezone = (dx as NSString).substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 19,length: 5))
let dateIntermediate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(timestamp)! / 1000)

let outp = NSDateFormatter()
outp.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm::ssSSS"
outp.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)

let input = outp.stringFromDate(dateIntermediate) + " " + timezone
let inp = NSDateFormatter()
inp.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm::ssSSS Z"

let finalDate = inp.dateFromString(input)
print(finalDate)
```

Let me explain:

- we extract the millisecond timestamp and the timezone from the original string
- we create a date from the timestamp to be able to split it into its different components
- we output that date in a more standard way (not as timestamp) and append the previously extracted timezone to that string
- we then read that string and parse a date from it again

*Note*
As @Phoen1xUK mentioned the timestamp *might* have a different length than 13 digits. You can handle that situation by stripping the `/Date(` and `)/` and then splitting the string before the `-` (or `+`).

Comment: Going on @WhiteRice's question, this is a good answer, but you were correct in your comment on the question that the time is in milliseconds since 1970 (unix/posix/epoch time) so you don't need to divide the timestamp by 1000.

Comment: @Phoen1xUK I do have to divide  because the time interval is in seconds, the fractional part of the double represents the milliseconds

Comment: `NSTimeInterval is always specified in seconds; it yields sub-millisecond precision over a range of 10,000 years.`

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Just one thing though, specifying a specific length of 13 for the timestamp's substring would not work indefinitely, and also not for times that were defined long ago.

Comment: @Phoen1xUK what exactly do you mean? you refer to the timestamp being 14 digits long? That is not really about to happen any time soon - technically you are right, but it does not matter here. I will include it in the answer however as remark.

Comment: Yea that's what I'm referring to. For example if referring to a date such as in 1970, the timestamp would be significantly shorter than 13 digits.