# Use JSON.NET to parse json date of format Date(epochTime-offset)

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone, json.net

I am using Json.net 7.0.1 in C# to consume a rest API. The trouble is with the date format the API uses in its JSON response. It looks like this:

```
/Date(1445301615000-0700)/
```

That is meant to represent a UTC time of 2015-10-19 17:40:15

If you plug 1445301615000 into an [epoch time converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/), you see that it is 2015-10-**20** **00**:40:15 . So it is 7 hours ahead of UTC. Then they include the -0700 presumably to offset that back to UTC. So, in an effort to give me a UTC time, they are sending me UTC+7-0700. Why they do it this way I have no idea, but I can't change that.

My question is, how best to make Json.NET parse that date string and come up with a DateTime of `2015-10-19 17:40:15` UTC. I can write a custom JsonConverter to hijack the value and manipulate it manually, but I was wondering if there is a more native method.

I have tried changing the `JsonSerializerSettings DateTimeZoneHandling` property to all its different values. Setting it to Utc just ignores the time zone offset, yielding `2015-10-20 00:40:15`. Setting it to Local, Unspecified, or RoundtripKind all yield `2015-10-19 20:40:15`, which I believe is because my local timezone is UTC-4, so it is trying to apply that adjustment to the main date value of 2015-10-20 00:40.

I also considered using the `DateFormatString` property to represent the expected date string format. But I could not find the right [format string characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) to represent this epochtime-offset format.

Here's a simplified example:

```
Person person;
string json = @"{ 'Name': 'John', 
                  'LastSeen':'/Date(1445301615000-0700)/' }";   // 1445301615000 = 2015-10-20 00:40:15

person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json);
Console.WriteLine(person.LastSeen);     // 10/19/2015 8:40:15 PM    Kind = Local

person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat });
Console.WriteLine(person.LastSeen);     // 10/19/2015 8:40:15 PM    Kind = Local

person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc });
Console.WriteLine(person.LastSeen);     // 10/20/2015 00:40:15 PM    Kind = Utc

// In all three, the -0700 portion is being ignored. I'd like person.LastSeen to be 10/19/2015 17:40:15.
```

Again, I could just know that the API is going to give me UTC+7 and do the adjustment myself to get real UTC. But I wondered if Json.NET has a native way to handle this type of date string.

Comment: Have you read http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm ?

Comment: I have indeed, and much of the surrounding documentation. I found plenty about parsing a normal "Microsoft Format" date string like Date(1445301615000), but nothing about this particular format with the -0700 offset added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> /Date(1445301615000-0700)/
>
> That is meant to represent a UTC time of 2015-10-19 17:40:15

Sorry, that's incorrect.  The UTC time is `2015-10-20 00:45:15`.  Your value corresponds to the *local* time, in a time zone with a `-07:00` offset at that instant.

In this [screwy format](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx), the timestamp portion is still based solely on UTC.  The offset is *extra* information. It doesn't change the timestamp.  You can give a different offset, or omit it entirely and it's still the same moment in time.

All of the following are equivalent, with regard to point-in-time.

```
/Date(1445301615000-0700)/
/Date(1445301615000)/
2015-10-20T00:40:15Z
2015-10-19T17:40:15-07:00
```

Notice that in in the ISO format, the offset *does* change the value, but in the MS format it does not.

It would be best if you did not use this format, as ISO8601 is a much saner choice for JSON.  However if you're stuck with it, then it's best not to deserialize it to a `DateTime`.  Instead, use a `DateTimeOffset`.

Consider:

```
string s = "\"/Date(1445301615000-0700)/\"";
DateTime dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(s);
Console.WriteLine(dt.Kind); // Local
```

That's no good.  basically, if there is *any* offset, it thinks it's your local time zone, which it might be, but it might not be.

```
string s = "\"/Date(1445301615000)/\"";
DateTime dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(s);
Console.WriteLine(dt.Kind); // Utc
```

This is ok, but you've lost track of that local time.

```
string s = "\"/Date(1445301615000-0700)/\"";
DateTimeOffset dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTimeOffset>(s);
Console.WriteLine(dto); // 10/19/2015 5:40:15 PM -07:00
```

That's much better.  And if you do indeed want a UTC `DateTime`, then:

```
string s = "\"/Date(1445301615000-0700)/\"";
DateTimeOffset dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTimeOffset>(s);
DateTime utc = dto.UtcDateTime;
Console.WriteLine(utc); // 10/20/2015 12:40:15 AM
```

So the key lesson is, regardless of format, if there is time zone offset information present in the data, then deserialize to `DateTimeOffset`.  While using `DateTime` *might* work in some cases, you are asking .NET to interpret the offset and apply default behavior, which often will not be the *desired* behavior.

Comment: Yep, I agree 100% that the makers of the API are misusing the date format. I've raised it as a bug with them, but not expecting much... for now, in their minds `/Date(1445301615000-0700)/` = `UTC 2015-10-19 17:40:15`.  Crazy, I know, but hence my problems.

Thanks for the excellent explanation, and the suggestion to use DateTimeOffset instead. I think that will be the cleanest way to go. Thanks!

Comment: You could compensate on your side, but then when they fix the bug then you'll have to unwind.  To compensate, do `dto.UtcDateTime + dto.Offset`.   (what a hack, indeed!)  Point them at this post if they need clarification - or give them my email. :)

Answer (score 3):

The `-hhmm` indicates that a local time was serialized, not a UTC time. .NET, like many other platforms, recognizes the concept of time zones. In .NET, for example, the `DateTime` class has a property indicating what kind of date/time you're dealing with. You can explicitly construct date/times of different kinds. The debugger is terrible for not pointing this out, but you can see it with the following code.

```
var dt1 = new DateTime(2015, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00); // defaults to DateTimeKind.Unspecified
var dt2 = new DateTime(2015, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Local);
var dt3 = new DateTime(2015, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var dt4 = new DateTime(2015, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
Debug.WriteLine(dt1.Kind); // writes "Unspecified"
Debug.WriteLine(dt2.Kind); // writes "Local"
Debug.WriteLine(dt3.Kind); // writes "Utc"
Debug.WriteLine(dt4.Kind); // writes "Unspecified"
```

You can then see the effect the DateTimeKind has on the Json with the following

```
// local time -- default datetime handling from JSON.NET
{
    var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    var jsonObject = new JObject {["dateTime"] = dateTime};
    var jsonString = jsonObject.ToString();
    Debug.WriteLine(jsonString); // uses "2015-10-19T18:13:53.4698565-04:00" form
}
// UTC time -- default datetime handling from JSON.NET
{
    var dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
    var jsonObject = new JObject {["dateTime"] = dateTime };
    var jsonString = jsonObject.ToString();
    Debug.WriteLine(jsonString); // uses "2015-10-19T22:13:53.5166571Z" form
}
// local time -- Microsoft-like datetime handling from JSON.NET
{
    var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    var jsonObject = new JObject {["dateTime"] = dateTime };
    var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject, new JsonSerializerSettings { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat });
    Debug.WriteLine(jsonString); // uses "/Date(1445292833516-0400)/" format
}
// local time -- Microsoft-like datetime handling from JSON.NET
{
    var dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
    var jsonObject = new JObject {["dateTime"] = dateTime };
    var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject, new JsonSerializerSettings { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat });
    Debug.WriteLine(jsonString); // uses "/Date(1445292833579)/" form
}
```

Comment: Good info, thanks. Of course in my case I'm trying to deserialize rather than serialize. I believe setting `DateFormatHanding = MicrosoftDataFormat` only affects how json is written, not how it is read. I'll add a more detailed example to my question.

Comment: This is mostly good info, though I recommend `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()`.  However, it doesn't quite address the deserialization concern.  Still a +1.

Comment: Understood. I was just supplying the background on how that value got put in there. Was assuming OP could figure the rest out himself. :)