# Powershell ConvertToJson date serialization

Tags: json, powershell

I am running into date issues when serializing to json from Powershell using the ConverTo-Json commandlet.

It generates dates that look like this:

```
"\/Date(1476684000000)\/"
```

I need it to generate a date with an offset that looks like:

```
"\/Date(1476684000000-0600)\/"
```

I can't seem to find anything in the docs that allows me to specify this.  Do I need to do this myself by hand?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am simply hand crafting the request:

```
$json= @"
{ "theDateParam" = "$(GetTodayInJson)" }
"@


Invoke-RestMethod 'http://myServer:myPort/json/reply/TheServiceOperation' -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType 'application/json'

Function GetTodayInJson()
{
    $now = [DateTime]::Now.Date
    $utcOffset = [TimeZone]::CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset($now)
    $utcOffsetString = $utcOffset.ToString("hhmm")
    $milliseconds = ($now.Subtract($utcOffset) - (new-object DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0))).TotalMilliseconds
    $result = "\/Date($milliseconds-$utcOffsetString)\/"
    return $result
}
```

This seems to do the trick.  Without the offset, my dates were arriving at the other end with the wrong time (actually I'm trying to remove the time component by making everything at midnight, but without the offset the date was showing up as 6pm on the server side).

If there is a better way to achieve this, please let me know.  Answers that include "change your date format" will not work for me.

Comment: Probably best approach.  My notes seemed to bring me to this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33224540/use-json-net-to-parse-json-date-of-format-dateepochtime-offset which seemed like a non-starter, and because I could, I used a different format.