# Different JSON DateTime deserialization among .NET Core and Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, json.net

On a SQLServer database table I have two birth dates:

1975-10-11 00:00:00.000

1983-07-19 00:00:00.000

A service (not mine) exposes the birthdates as JSON, with DateTime in the following format (I can't change it):

"/Date(182210400000-0000)/"

"/Date(427413600000-0000)/"

The basic code for test:

```
response = await client.PostAsync(uri, contentReq);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var contentResp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine("JSON:" + contentResp);

                    var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(contentResp);


                    TimeSpan ts1 = new DateTimeOffset(user.BirthDate.Value).Offset;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Offset:{ts1.ToString()}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Data:{user.BirthDate.Value.ToString()}");
}
```

Output on .NET5 Console app:

Offset:02:00:00

Date:11/10/1975 00:00:00

Offset:02:00:00

Date:19/07/1983 00:00:00

Output on a Xamarin Android App:

**Offset:01:00:00**

**Date:10/10/1975 23:00:00**

Offset:02:00:00

Date:19/07/1983 00:00:00

Please help me understand the Xamarin error in deserialization. Why on just one of the values?
I tried other dates and times, and result is unpredictable.

UPDATE1:

tested with and without

```
 JsonSerializerSettings microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
            };
```

and adding

```
var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(contentResp,microsoftDateFormatSettings);
```

Comment: it looks like it is using the MS serialization format, not ISO.  See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm

Comment: yes, but I need to decode the MS format. Is still valid, and on that page it says JSON.NET maintains compatibility

Comment: I would try explicitly setting DateFormatHandling to MS to see if that generates more consistent results

Comment: I tried, results are the same

Comment: are all platforms using the same Newtonsoft version and same locale settings?

Comment: same version, latest. same locale, same timezone. what I don't get is why some values are deserialized correctly, other not, on the same platform

Comment: dunno, I would open an issue with Newtonsoft

Comment: What happens if you explicitly set [`JsonSerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DateTimeZoneHandling.htm)?  Also, what version of Json.NET are you using on Xamarin and .NET Core?

Comment: By setting UTC, I get 22PM of the day before, with both dates. I opened an issue here https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2548 but it turned out that is not a json.net issue, but more a DST issue and a different way to calculate the localtime in Windows/NET and Linux/Mono starting from UTC. In WIndows localtime is UTC + current GMT (GMT +2 DST in italy now). In Android localtime is UTC + GMT of that time (so for winter dates is GMT +1). Or at least this is the experience with my tests.

Comment: Related: [Use JSON.NET to parse json date of format Date(epochTime-offset)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33224540/3744182).