# How to convert Objective-C to date format yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

The return period of the server is ‘/Date (1460510348510) /’  How to convert Objective-C to date format yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: What does that number represent?  Number of seconds since some date?  Phases of the moon?  Next week's lottery numbers?

Comment: That is (almost) the JSON encoding for a date as used by Microsoft's ASP.NET AJAX (and the number is the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 GMT). If you are interested in a Swift solution: [Parsing JSON (date) to Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908219/parsing-json-date-to-swift).

Comment: I know your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it is a timestamp, you can do the following to convert it into a `NSDate` object:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1460510348510/1000.0];
```

which prints out `2016-04-13 01:19:08 +0000` if you `NSLog` it.

--

How you can parse that response into an actual timestamp is described below:

[Parsing JSON (date) to Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908219/parsing-json-date-to-swift)