# json date to swift date \/date()\/

Tags: json, swift4

Help me out guys. Calling a JSON API and it's returning this type of date.

```
 "TransactionDate":"\/Date(1533096000000)\/"
```

How do I format this to something along the lines of MM/dd/yyyy ?

Comment: Use `Decodable`, decode the date as `Date` passing `.millisecondsSince1970` date decoding strategy and use a `DateFormatter` to get the desired string format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON (date) to Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908219/parsing-json-date-to-swift)